# VBA - Check for unique values, for each of those check if another value exists in the rows that contain unique value

Tags: excel, vba

So i realise that the title is a bit loose..

So for each of the unique values in Column B I need to check if there the value 'PDO' exists in Column C - PDO can and must only exist once per unique value in Column B. There can be many rows with the same unique name.

Example Data - My actual sheet has many other columns but i only need to concentrate on these below - The data needs to be in this format for the 3rd party system, there is a merged cell above the main data that i am ignoring here.

| Org | Name | Shift Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC Co | WkPtn1 | M2Sa |
| ABC Co | WkPtn1 | PDO |
| ABC Co | WkPtn2 | M2F |
| ABC Co | WkPtn2 | PDO |
| ABC Co | WkPtn3 | M2F |
| ABC Co | WkPtn3 | M2Sa |

I have got as far as extracting the list of unique names into another sheet with the below.
rwCnt is declared further up in the sheet as -
`rwCnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))`

```
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, z As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
c = Range("B3:B" & rwCnt)
For z = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
d(c(z, 1)) = 1
Next z
Sheets("Temp").Range("A2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
```

My thought was to get each of the values from the main data, pop it in a temp sheet and then lookup the cells in the main data, however i think this is overdoing it and would run fairly slow.

As a bonus: To follow my other error checking, I would also like to keep a number stored of lines that have an issue (i pop a message to the user at the end of the checks telling them how many issues)
Possibly even insert a duplicate line with the value PDO in it.

Comment: Probably doable using `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` and checking if the result = 1.

Comment: What do you need in the end - a sheet with names where shift name PDO is missing?

Comment: @Ike I would like to do it in line where possible (added bonus section at the end of my question) but yes could also be a list dumped into another sheet

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use VBA? Can't you just add a helper column with a `COUNTIFS`? Then you can filter the data to highlight those with 0 or >1 as required?

Comment: @Gravitate - no direct need, just trying to automate as much as possible for the end user so it (the data) can all be checked with a single button click